# Javascript não funciona no IE 11

Tags: javascript, script

Recentemente estava olhando em alguns sites e encontrei um código "[Dark Mode](https://codepen.io/PavelRodionoff/pen/MdQdjw)", porém ao testá-lo percebi que ele não funciona no IE 11.

No modo desenvolvedor do IE consta que o erro é "Sintaxe".

Código:

```
const switchTumbler = () => {
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".tumbler__wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener("click", () => {
toggleNightMode();
});
};
switchTumbler();
const toggleNightMode = () => {
document.body.classList.toggle("body--night-mode");
document.querySelector(".tumbler").classList.toggle("tumbler--night-mode");
document.querySelectorAll(".post").forEach(post => {
post.classList.toggle("post--night-mode");
});
};
```

Poderiam me ajudar, gostaria de usa-lo no IE, porém sou leigo em javascript.

Comment: O `IE11` não suporta a função `.toggle` de `classList`. Você de usar a opção `add` e `remove`, apenas.

Comment: Existe um site que pessoalmente eu acho bem legal para verificar a compatibilidade de navegadores: https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @ValdeirPsr aqui funcionou o `.toggle` normal ;)

Comment: @sam Vi no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), mas me confundi. O que não funciona é o segundo parâmetro. Grato pela correção. 

Answer (score 4):

O IE11 não suporta *arrow functions*, *classList* (algumas versões) nem `-forEach` em coleções, só em Arrays. 
Tens de usar JavaScript mais antigo. Podes mudar o código para algo assim:

- `() => {}` muda para `function(){}`
- `.classList` muda para uma função que faça isso
- `.forEach` usa o método da Array assim `Array.prototype.forEach.call(`

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/WNeKpJE

```js
function toggleNightMode() {
  console.log("toggleNightMode");
  toggleClass(document.body, "body--night-mode");
  toggleClass(document.querySelector(".tumbler"), "tumbler--night-mode");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(".post"), 
  function(post) {
    toggleClass(post, "post--night-mode");
  });
}

function toggleClass(el, clss) {
  let classes = [];
  if (el.className.indexOf(clss) === -1) {
    classes = el.className.split(" ").concat(clss);
  } else {
    classes = el.className.split(clss);
  }
  el.className = classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

function switchTumbler() {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".tumbler__wrapper");
  wrapper.addEventListener("click", toggleNightMode);
}
switchTumbler();
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o IE11 não suporta as *arrows functions* e o `.forEach`. Na versão atualizada que testei aqui, o `classList` funcionou perfeitamente.

O que você tem que fazer é trocar as `arrows functions` por `function()` e o `.forEach` por um `for` comum. Veja no gif abaixo que nenhum erro de JavaScript é retornado no console e o código roda normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código irá ficar desta forma:

```
const switchTumbler = function() {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.tumbler__wrapper')

  wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggleNightMode()
  })
}                          

switchTumbler()

const toggleNightMode = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('body--night-mode')
  document.querySelector('.tumbler').classList.toggle('tumbler--night-mode')
  const posts = document.querySelectorAll('.post')
  for(let x=0; x < posts.length; x++){
    posts[x].classList.toggle('post--night-mode')
  }
}
```

Versão do IE11 testado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]